# Arguments for TFS Visual studio merge too

Tags: visual-studio, merge, tfs

I was using WinMerge as my merge tool in Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise.  I'm trying to switch back to the default Team Foundation Server merge tool.  I went to Tools -> Options -> Source Control -> Visual Studio Team Foundation Server.  Clicked Configuration Tools...  I already had a Merge operation.  I click Modify and I put in the path to vsDiffMerge.exe, but I don't know the arguments.  What would they be to use the default merge tool?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go back to the default, just remove the "merge" option completely.  Visual Studio will use its default compare tool.